# Xamarin.Android not hitting breakpoints in library project (Visual Studio for Mac)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android (12.0) project that references a .Net Standard 2.0 library that contains all the code for the business logic of the app.

When I drop a breakpoint in the Android project in Visual Studio for Mac, they work as expected. However when I put a breakpoint in the library project, the breakpoints stay "hollow" and are never hit during execution. Hovering over the breakpoints doesn't reveal any further information, they just "don't work".

Is there a way to troubleshoot breakpoints in VS?

This is in both Visual Studio for Mac 17.0.2 and also the Preview 17.3

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem?Could you please post the steps to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac.